# Concatenate two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have:

Table1

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ AGE ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════╣
║  0 ║ John  ║  15 ║
║  1 ║ Chris ║  20 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

Table2

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ OCCUPATION ║   ADDRESS   ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║  0 ║ Bus Driver ║ None        ║
║  1 ║ Lawyer     ║ some adress ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Desired output**:

Table 3

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ AGE ║ OCCUPATION ║   ADDRESS   ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║  0 ║ John  ║  15 ║ Bus Driver ║ None        ║
║  1 ║ Chris ║  20 ║ Lawyer     ║ some adress ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

While I can accomplish this task by using PHP `mysql_query("SELECT .. "); mysql_query("INSERT ..");` -ish ways, I want to use pure SQL for this task.

Comment: +1 just for taking your time and designed your tables with the wish of output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  t1.Name,
  t1.Age,
  t2.Occupation,
  t2.Address
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31358/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID |  NAME | AGE | OCCUPATION |     ADDRESS |
-----------------------------------------------
|  0 |  John |  15 | Bus Driver |        None |
|  1 | Chris |  20 |     Lawyer | some adress |
```

---

If you want to create a new table `table3` directly from this select, do this:

```
CREATE Table Table3
AS 
SELECT
  t1.Name,
  t1.Age,
  t2.Occupation,
  t2.Address
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

[**Like this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ac4f/1)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 SELECT t1.* , t2.* 
 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcd03/1)

Comment: This is nice, too. Also short. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do,

```
SELECT a.id, name, age, occupation, address
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: I would rather `SELECT a.*, b.*` like in echo_me's solution, but this works too. Thank you!

Comment: @TheConjuring Putting * would give you the column `id` twice. This will give the output as was requested in the question.